# Automatically check a CheckBox if file exists

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a program such that if the file exists, the checkbox will auto check.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //check whether the file is exist or not
  if (string curFile = @"C:\s\test.txt")
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Include "Using System.IO" at top of code.
after: this line is an exemple:
checkBox1.Checked = File.Exists(@"c:\PathToFile\file.txt")?true:false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use the System.IO to verify if the file exist and then set the atributte .checked to true. Something like this:

```
    if System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\s\test.txt") {
        yourcheckbox.checked = true
    }
    else {
        yourcheckbox.checked = false
    }
```

Comment: checked = Checked

Answer (score 0):

`File.Exists(fileLocation)` returns a bool

Answer (score 0):

Since `File.Exists()` returns `true` or `false` then you can use the returned value directly as such:

```
yourcheckbox.Checked = File.Exists(@"c:\Path\To\File.txt");
```

Which would be equivalent to doing something like this:

```
bool didItExist = File.Exists(@"c:\path\to\file.txt");
checkbox.Checked = didItExist;
```

And/or this

```
checkbox.Checked = File.Exists(@"c:\path\to\file.txt") ? true : false;
```

Don't forget to add a `using System.IO;` at the top because `File.Exists()` derives from it.

I think the first suggested alternative is the most concise way of doing it.

Following up on your comment... here's a fully functional snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace AutoCheckCheckbxIfFileExist_45245562
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            /*
             * I'm adding the fields dynamically through code so that
             * you know all the fields that are on my form.
             * Because they are created dynamically, I'll use 'Find' later on
             * to retrieve them.
             */
            addButton();
            addTextField();
            addChkbx();
        }

        private void addChkbx()
        {

            /*
             * This is the checkbox that will be dyamically checked or unchecked
             */
            CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
            chkbx.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 35, this.Location.Y + 55);
            chkbx.Name = "thechkbx";
            this.Controls.Add(chkbx);
        }

        private void addTextField()
        {
            /*
             * This is the field I'll be looking at to pull the file path
             */
            TextBox txtb = new TextBox();
            txtb.Name = "txtbx_thebox";
            txtb.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.X + 35);
            this.Controls.Add(txtb);
        }

        private void addButton()
        {
            /*
             * This will be the button you'll click on to get the check/uncheck behavior
             */
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "ClickMe";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            btn.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * This is the answer to your question
             * Because I dynamically create the fields, I'm using a Find to get them and use them.
             */
            ((CheckBox)this.Controls.Find("thechkbx", true)[0]).Checked = File.Exists(((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtbx_thebox", true)[0]).Text);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not work, after i run my code, the checkbox still uncheck.